# Chart JS only showing first 2 values

Tags: python, flask

I'm using this for my chart application right now

```
<script>
    var canvas = document.getElementById('myChart');

    new Chart(document.getElementById("myCanvas"), {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: mon_unique,
    datasets: [{
        data: values,
        borderColor: "#3e95cd",
        fill: false
      },
    ]
    },
    options: {
        title: {
        display: true,
        },
            hover: {
            mode: 'index',
            intersect: true
            },
        }
    });
    
    </script>
```

values, what I called my data in my flask app, is a list of numbers. When I change data: [0,1,2,3,4] it graphs it, but it doesn't pass in my values at all.

```
data = remove_err_str
return render_template('graphing.html', values=data)
```

---

This displays only the first two points in values. Values is a list of about 50,000 items. It looks like ['1243.42','2`,...]

```
<body>
    <canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
    <script>
      var canvas = document.getElementById('myChart');
  
      new Chart(document.getElementById("myChart"), {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
      datasets: [{
          data: {{values | safe}},
          borderColor: "#3e95cd",
          fill: false
        },
      ]
      },
      options: {
          title: {
          display: true,
          test: "Chart for the sweep data"
          },
              hover: {
              mode: 'index',
              intersect: true
              },
          }
      });
      
      </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution I found
Graphing HTML page

```
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.0.0/Chart.bundle.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <canvas id="myChart" width="1600" height="800"></canvas>
    <script>
        var canvas = document.getElementById('myChart');
        var chart = new Chart(canvas, {
            type: 'line',
            data: {
                labels: {{ labels | safe }},
                datasets: [{
                    label: "Line chart for sweep data",
                    data: {{ values | safe }},
                    fill: false
                }]
            },
            options: {
                responsive: false,
                scales: {
                    yAxes: [{
                        ticks: {
                            beginAtZero: true
                            }
                        }]
                    }}}
                );
</script>
```

Every item needs a label. If it gets passed in without a label it won't graph. Also I changed the 'beginAtZero' to be set to true, otherwise it starts the lowest y value in the list. To create labels for every value I did this in my flask app.py

```
for i in data: #turns it from a list of string values to float values
    float_data.append(float(i))
    count = count + 1
    label_arr.append(count)
return render_template('graphing.html', values=float_data, labels=label_arr)
```

:*]

Answer (score 0):

You are passing data from python-end to front-end so you have to use `jinja` template inside your code and for that `double-brackets` can be used

```
 <script>
    var canvas = document.getElementById('myChart');

    new Chart(document.getElementById("myCanvas"), {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: mon_unique,
    datasets: [{
        data: {{values | tojson}},
        borderColor: "#3e95cd",
        fill: false
      },
    ]
    },
    options: {
        title: {
        display: true,
        },
            hover: {
            mode: 'index',
            intersect: true
            },
        }
    });
    
    </script>
```

Comment: When I do that, all I get is a blank screen. Values is a list of comma separated values.

Comment: Go to console or elements tab in developer mode and see are you able to see your values or have you included your canvas tag or use `tojson` instead of `safe`

Comment: I had an error with my labels that the console told me about so that fixed that issue. It's now only displaying the first two values of the list I have

Comment: I updated the code to show what it looks like now.

Comment: It may show 2 values because of so much data and chart is appearing ??